# How to convert a string into and array?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
countries = "India,Bangladesh,Srilanka,South Africa,Australia,Canada"
```

I need to get an array from it:

```
countries = ["India","Bangladesh","Srilanka","South Africa","Australia","Canada"]
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the `split` method:

```
countries = countries.split(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
countries = "India,Bangladesh,Srilanka,South Africa,Australia,Canada".split(',')
```

Comment: Or even better, don't have an intermediate string.  Simply do what you are doing, as `countries ="India,Bangladesh,Srilanka,South Africa,Australia,Canada".split(',')`